# Sum up value if greater then previous value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to keep summing up the values only if previous value is greater than my current value (summed up value). I tried doing cumsum but I'm not able to do it based on a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.where to determine whether to keep the old value or take the cumsum:

```
df['finalvalue'] = (
    np.where(df.value.gt(df.value.shift())[::-1], 
             df.value, df.iloc[::-1].value.cumsum()[::-1])
)
```

Comment: Hi Allen, 
I'm not getting the expected results